# Inheritance in Javascript - protoyping not in definition-part?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype

I am currently switching from AS3 to JavaScript.
I still have some trouble with understanding inheritance-concepts.
What I do not understand is why the following code is not working properly:

```
Base = function () {
    this.coolVar = "great";
}  

SmallControl = function () {

    // Inheritance:
    this.prototype = new Base();
    this.prototype.constructor = SmallControl;

    this.prototype.init = function(aMap) {
        console.log('init');
        console.log('coolVar?: ' + this.coolVar);
    }
}  
var foo = new SmallControl();  
//foo.init();         // --> TypeError: foo.init is not a function  
foo.prototype.init(); // --> works
```

If I put the prototype definitions outside of the "SmallControl"-Function everything works fine... but I don't understand that.

Comment: From first glance it seems to me that when you defined: this.prototype.init you defined init on the prototype object NOT the SmallControl object because 'this' isn't the same as SmallControl - it's the "current object" at runtime instantiation of a SmallControl. That's why foo.prototype.init does work. When you say "put the prototype definitions outside..." I assume you did: SmallControl.prototype = function init(aMap) - yes, that will work and is the idiom when doing classical inheritance. Examples: 
http://github.com/roblevintennis/Testing-and-Debugging-JavaScript/tree/master/code/objects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
// Create the super class
Base = function () {
    this.coolVar = "great";
};  

// Create the new class
SmallControl = function () {
}; 
// Set the prototype of SmallControl to be an instance of Base. 
// This runs the Base constructor _immediately_ which sets up the variable
SmallControl.prototype = new Base();
// Add the init method to the SmallControl class
SmallControl.prototype.init = function(aMap) {
    console.log('init');
    console.log('coolVar?: ' + this.coolVar);
}
// Create an instance of SmallControl    
var foo = new SmallControl();  
foo.init();
```

Comment: -- David -- nice classical inheritance example! Roman, this WILL work. However, if you need more efficiency you will want to research: "Constructor Stealing". Then you will want to replace the 
SmallControl.prototype = new Base(); line because you will be calling the super's constructor twice. You'll then need to implement a helper method to inheritcProto(Sub, Sup). I have all of this code working and TDD'd here: http://github.com/roblevintennis/Testing-and-Debugging-JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

`prototype` is only a meaningful property of constructors.  The object's actual prototype (which is accessible in some environments as the property `__proto__`, but this is not portable) is set to be the constructor's `prototype` attribute at the time the object is constructed.  Changes to the constructor's prototype (adding properties to the prototype) will be reflected in live objects, but not if you set `Constructor.prototype` to be a completely different object.

In your constructor, you're setting the `prototype` attribute *of the constructed object* (`this`).  This attribute has no special meaning on something that's not a constructor function.  When you set it outside of the function, you set it on the constructor function.